# Word for: a synonym with a positive connotation?

Tags: synonyms, connotation

For example:

"Cautious is just a _________ for being scared."

"Opportunistic is just a _________ for being inconsiderate."

"Not too bright is just a _________ for being dumb."

"Simple is just a _________ for being ignorant.

The word is used often in politics to expose someone as being partial to a particular idea or identity. The word in question has a similar nature to the word "pseudonym".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the word you want is **euphemism**.  According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism),

> euphemism - noun
>
> 1. The substitution of an agreeable or inoffensive expression for one that may offend or suggest something unpleasant
> 2. The expression so substituted

It fits all your examples, e.g. "Cautious is just a euphemism for being scared."

Comment: Yes! This was the one. I went blank this evening and had no idea where to start when searching for the word online. It's not exactly easy to describe.

Comment: A funny thing about euphemisms is that people quickly catch on to the fact that they mean the same thing as the offensive/unpleasant words they replace, and new euphemisms must take their place. (Consider `crippled`=>`handicapped`=>`disabled`)  This is known as the "Euphemism Treadmill".

Answer (score 1):

It's

a ***[politically correct](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/politically-correct) word or expression*** ,

which is  used instead of another one to avoid being offensive:

"Some people think 
that "fireman" is a sexist term, and prefer the politically correct term 
"firefighter"."

There is also a special term 
**circumlocution**.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumlocution?topic=digressing-and-being-indirect-or-evasive) :

***Circumlocution***

(an example of) an indirect way of saying something, especially something unpleasant:

"Economical with the truth" is a circumlocution for "lying".

// Politicians are experts in circumlocution.

Comment: Not the word I was thinking of, but good effort! I dare say political discourse is often pure circumlocution.

Comment: -1 "Politically correct" has a deeper meaning than "a nice way of saying". Its meaning becomes diluted when over applied like this.